# Silverlight Deployment

Tags: silverlight, deployment

I have a Silverlight 2.0 site that works in dev.  I have Copy Local set to true for System.Web.Silverlight (not sure if that is necessary).  In production the web page loads, and the JS is sent to the client, but the movie is not loaded.

Does the server need anything special installed? (it has 3.5 SP1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a fairly long answer to similar [problem in Silverlight publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962005/problem-in-silverlight-publish/964098#964098) question.

Quick summary:

1. Server doesn't need anything special - it just sends the XAP file to the browser. Unix servers have no problem hosting Silverlight apps.
2. Do you see the 'blue loading swirl' or just a blank white area? If no loading indicator, your XAP file probably isn't downloading.
3. Can you download the XAP file directly or do you get a 404 (eg. type http://yourserver.com/ClientBin/YourSLApp.xap and see if you get a download prompt or not). If you get a 404 then your server is blocking the download. Try renaming your .XAP to .ZIP (and updating your HTML OBJECT tag)
4. If your Silverlight app loads correctly but it isn't displaying some content (eg images or movies) then once again check you can download them directly from the browser, and verify the URL you've put in your Silverlight app are correct, ESPECIALLY if they are relative paths.

Answer (score 2):

Have you registered the .xap mime type in IIS?

.xap         application/x-silverlight-app

Comment: This is the answer if you're trying to run Silverlight out of IIS 6

Answer (score 0):

Where is located your movie ? Can you give us some more details about your project architecture ?

If your Silverlight application can be loaded, maybe it is just a security access issue with your movie file.