# problem in Silverlight publish

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, publishing

I have a silverlight 2.0 object on content of masterpage. i see it on local but can't see on the host after publishing. according to Microsoft blog i add 2 MIME type of xaml and xap but silverlight object doesn't appear. i can't see the content of silverlight object but i can configure silverlight by right click. please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can right-click and get the Silverlight menu, your `object` tag is obviously rendering OK, which is a good start.

You don't mention whether you see the "percent loading" blue-dot animation? If that appears then the plugin is loading your XAP file - BUT if you *don't* see the loading animation it's likely that there is a problem "getting" the XAP file itself. There are two common reasons:

1) The **server won't serve XAP files**. This is actually quite common as by default IIS won't serve unknown file extensions, and for many hosting providers this includes `.XAP`. Checking this is very easy: just put the path to your XAP in the browser and try to download it... eg. http://racereplay.net/ClientBin/Silverlight2.xap should pop-up a "Download this file" dialog.

IF you get a [**404 Page Not Found**](http://racereplay.net/ClientBin/Silverlight3.xap) then this is why your page isn't working.

The fix in this case is either (i) update the IIS settings (you say you've setup the MIME types already, so just check they are correct) OR (ii) RENAME your `.XAP` to `.ZIP` (both the file itself AND in the `<object>` tag). Most servers have no problem with ZIP files, and Silverlight doesn't mind either.

2) The **path to the XAP** might be wrong. Double-check that the path is correct, say for this example

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
<param name="source" value="../ClientBin/Silverlight2.xap"/>
```

if the above tag is at `http://racereplay.net/SmhHalf/default.aspx`... copy the XAP path (source) onto the URL and verify that you get prompted to download the file, eg
[`http://racereplay.net/SmhHalf/../ClientBin/Silverlight2.xap`](http://racereplay.net/SmhHalf/../ClientBin/Silverlight2.xap)

The fix in this case is simply to get the path right. You mention the `<object>` tag is on a Masterpage, so you'll probably want an *absolute* path (eg. "/ClientBin/Your.XAP") because I guess your Masterpage could be used in `/default.aspx` and also in any subdirectory on your site (`/AboutUs/Help.aspx` or whatever).

As Anthony said, the software on the server is irrelevant (except for the web server allowing `.XAP` files to be downloaded), so don't worry about .NET versions there.

If you update your post as you try these suggestions (and perhaps the actual URLs themselves) others may be able to offer more advice.

Answer (score 0):

Debug with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to see what is actually being requested.  Are you sure you've published the XAP in the place the HTML expects it to be (typically the ClientBin folder)?

**Edit**:

Supplementary question is "silverlight 2.0 needs .NET 3.0 or 3.5 on host?"

Which version of .NET is running on the host is not important.  Its possible to deliver a silverlight app in plain old HTML.

Comment: thanks AnthonyWJones. Yes i sure published the xap file in the right location. at additional my hosting support .NET 2.0. my new question is: Is silverlight 2.0 needs .NET 3.0 or 3.5 on host?

Answer (score 0):

If you are consuming a WCF webservice, make sure you have a clientaccesspolicy.xml file in your iis' root directory.  If you are calling the service on start up, it could cause the project to throw an exception and halt execution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the shared web hosting. After rename the xap file to 'zip' and update the file name in the  tag, my first silverlight application is working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yep as u guys said i had prob too but as i changed de file extension to zip it worked..

Seems gotta add xap extension in IIS in MIME

thnx guys.